# Primitive type immutability and stack?

Tags: c#, stack, primitive

I was reading 'CLR via C#' and while going over 'how things relate at runtime' and 'primitive, reference and value types' I got confused a bit. 
If I have the below code called from Main -

```
void DoSomething(int x) 
{
  int m = x/2;
  int n = SomeMethod1(m);
      n = (n * 2) + x; 
  int k = SomeMethod2(n);
      m += (k*3);
}
```

The code does nothing useful but I am just trying to understand the behavior of the local integer variables and memory allocation.

I understand m, n and k reside on the stack?
Now, for the last line (I'm ignoring the variable n) the value of 'm' has to be modified. So everything else on the stack has to be popped off and the value of 'm' be updated? Is this negligible compared to the overhead of boxing and unboxing on heap? Will it become significant if the stack height is more?

P.S: Am excluding GC from discussion (for boxing and unboxing) which is definitely an overhead and also this is only to try and understand the behavior and may/may not be a practical scenario.

Comment: It looks like you do not understand how stack variable addressing works. It's not `pop`/`push`, it's simply offset from stack pointer, which is 1-2 cpu instructions (correct me if I am wrong). So there is no overhead compared to boxing/unboxing.

Comment: @Sinatr: It examines/compares every variable in the stack until it gets to 'm' and updates the value?

Comment: Not really, `m` is referenced as `ptr + 123` (to example), where `ptr` is stack pointer (register?) and `123` is an offset. So any operation with `m` doesn't depends on how *deep* it is in the stack. Also, perhaps you think, what `ptr` is *current stack pointer*, which changes after `n` and `k`? That's not right, `ptr` is constant for a process (thread?) and it's *beginning of stack* (or point of stack when entering function, which stay constant as well until function exit). Search `stack` explanation, perhaps [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html) can do.

Comment: @Sinatr: Thanks for the clarification. I was thinking more along the lines of the stack data structure.It makes more sense now. Would have accepted this as answer but Luaan has provided a similar reasoning in Answers below :)

Comment: Don't think about the *stack*, think about the *temporary storage pool*.  You can predict the lifetimes of those variables easily, which means that they are highly likely to go on the temporary storage pool. The temporary storage pool is likely to be implemented as a combination of stack and registers.  Also, **don't think of the stack as a stack**. The stack is better thought of as a one-million-byte *array*, rather than as the abstract data type we call a "stack".  Similarly, "the heap" has only the vaguest relationship to the "heap" data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing saying m, n or k should be on the stack. Most likely, they'll be in registers, and since you're not even using inter-dependence, they don't even have to be there at the same time. The JIT compiler is very good at runtime optimization, the stack is hardly ever used for anything but method parameters (or their references). And GC has no power in either the registers or the stack - the stack is deallocated the same way as in native code. Only the heap is a domain of the GC.

This is a common misunderstanding, because in IL (the intermediate language C# compiles into) actually *does* everything using the stack. However, that is *not* what executes on your machine - the IL code is compiled yet again by the JIT compiler. Of course, the JIT compiler is free to do everything on the stack as well, but that would be silly. Simple example time:

```
x + y
```

Would compile to this IL (in pseudo-code):

```
push y
push x
op_Add
```

So for a simple integer addition, it needs to do a method call and two pushes to stack. Not terribly expensive, but if you're trying to do any serious calculation, you're in trouble.

However, the JIT compiler will produce something more like this:

```
add ax, bx
```

It's very smart about this, so it in fact often uses registers even for method parameters - if it's safe.

However, note that all of this is just an implementation detail - in this case, a performance optimization. An integer might just as easily live on the heap (and in fact, it does if it's e.g. boxed or a part of another object that lives on the heap).

So, obviously, the fastest things are those that are supported inside the CPU itself - as in the example above, adding two registers together. Very fast.

Using the stack is usually still very fast. It's not that the allocation to the heap is expensive - in fact, heap and stack allocations are about the same cost. It's the deallocation that hurts - the heap needs to be garbage collected and compacted, while the stack only needs a single pointer change.

Oh, and you misunderstand the way you can access the stack. True, there's the basic `push` and `pop` instructions, however, those are not the *only* way. You can directly address the memory of the stack the same way you can address any other piece of memory. In fact, that's the whole point why you can see the stack pointers (like ESP).

Comment: If the ints were replaced with struct, will this still apply?

Comment: @Kodathon It might. Or it might not. It all depends on how those are used - for example, if you pass a struct into an interface parameter, the struct will necessarily be boxed, even if it implements that interface. There's a few things you want to avoid, but all in all, you shouldn't even care. Everything you're talking about is performance optimization, and you should really only start optimizing performance once it becomes a noticeable issue. Not to mention that it's very easy to "optimize" code to be much slower, more memory intensive, etc. Measurement is the key - profile, don't guess.

Comment: sure, I agree on when to start optimizing part. Not sure if my question was clear actually - I was only trying to understand if  it is feasible for the original scenario to occur and that modifying contents on stack CAN cause an impact?

Comment: I can upload a small screen capture from the book which can clarify but I can't include that in my question. Is there any other way I can clarify my question?

Comment: @Kodathon CLR via C# is a great book, and I'm sure the situation is explained better later. Modifying contents on the stack is not likely to cause a performance impact, because the stack most likely resides in the CPU cache - it will be somewhat slower than using registers directly, but with modern superscalar CPUs, it shouldn't pose a problem in the total throughput. You can address variables on the stack without having to `pop` them out - the stack is just another place in memory that happens to have a bunch of registers and instructions to simplify its use.

Comment: @Kodathon The only important thing to understand is that the `SomeMethod1` is not actually working with the local variable `m` - it will get a *copy* of `m` (regardless whether passed through the stack or registers), and that's guaranteed (the same way, a reference type will have its *reference* copied). In order to truly "share" the variable, you'd either have to wrap it in a reference, or use the `ref` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Every variable in that code is mutable and in stack!

If you want to get a sense what immutability is then read [**Eric Lippert**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) posts about **immutability**:

- [Immutability in C# Part One: Kinds of Immutability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx)
- [Immutability in C# Part Two: A Simple Immutable Stack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/04/immutability-in-c-part-two-a-simple-immutable-stack.aspx)
- [Immutability in C# Part Three: A Covariant Immutable Stack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/06/immutability-in-c-part-three-a-covariant-immutable-stack.aspx)
- [Immutability in C# Part Four: An Immutable Queue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/10/immutability-in-c-part-four-an-immutable-queue.aspx)
- [Immutability in C# Part Five: LOLZ!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/13/immutability-in-c-part-five-lolz.aspx)
- [Immutability in C# Part Seven: More on Binary Trees](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/19/immutability-in-c-part-seven-more-on-binary-trees.aspx?PageIndex=2)
- [Immutability in C# Part Eight: Even More On Binary Trees](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/01/18/immutability-in-c-part-eight-even-more-on-binary-trees.aspx)
- [Immutability in C# Part Nine: Academic? Plus my AVL tree implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/01/22/7190590.aspx)
- [Immutability in C# Part Ten: A double-ended queue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/01/22/immutability-in-c-part-10-a-double-ended-queue.aspx)
- [Immutability in C# Part Eleven: A working double-ended queue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/12/immutability-in-c-part-eleven-a-working-double-ended-queue.aspx)

There would be a slight difference between

```
m = m + (k*3);
m += (k*3);
```

Difference being that in second line is better because temporary registry element (m + (k*3)) in L1/L2 cache is not created and value is directly pushed back in the variable value slot. Making it 3-12 cycles faster (that is in order of less then 1% of 1 millisecond). Try to concentrate on things that matter.

Comment: I am not trying to find if m += (k*3) is faster than m = m + (k*3). I am not trying to optimize the code I posted (which doesn't do anything anyways). I was reading the book and just wondered if there is a possibility of any overhead at all with the stack at some point as the variable being modified is not at the top.

Comment: My punchline was that overhead exists for about everything, but you can neglect it as it is too small.

Comment: Fair enough :) I should have added 'overhead compared to heap allocation/de-allocation'